# Как исправить зависание интерфейса?

Tags: python, tkinter

Знаю, есть несколько тем на эту тему и практически везде помогает использование after.

Я хотел узнать как можно конкретно в моей программе это исправить?

Что должна делать программа в целом:

Есть квадрат, середины его сторон сжимаются до образования креста, а затем разжимаются. И так циклически. У меня же квадрат сжимается, но когда должно происходить разжимание, интерфейс виснет.

Код:

```
import time
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.title('main')
root.geometry('600x800')

c = Canvas(width=600, height=800, bg='white')
c.place(x=0, y=0)

n = 8


def start():
    global l1, l2, l3, l4, l5, l6, l7, l8
    l1 = c.create_line(200, 100, 300, 100)
    l2 = c.create_line(300, 100, 400, 100)
    l3 = c.create_line(400, 100, 400, 200)
    l4 = c.create_line(400, 200, 400, 300)
    l5 = c.create_line(400, 300, 300, 300)
    l6 = c.create_line(300, 300, 200, 300)
    l7 = c.create_line(200, 300, 200, 200)
    l8 = c.create_line(200, 200, 200, 100)



def delete_line():
    c.after(10, c.delete, l1)
    c.after(10, c.delete, l2)
    c.after(10, c.delete, l3)
    c.after(10, c.delete, l4)
    c.after(10, c.delete, l5)
    c.after(10, c.delete, l6)
    c.after(10, c.delete, l7)
    c.after(10, c.delete, l8)


def move():
    s = c.coords(l1)
    s1 = c.coords(l3)
    print(s1)
    s2 = c.coords(l5)
    s3 = c.coords(l7)

    if s[3] < 200:
        s[3] = s[3] + n
        c.coords(l1, 200, 100, 300, s[3])
        c.coords(l2, 300, s[3], 400, 100)
        print(s)
        print(s[3])
        c.after(0)

    if s1[2] > 300:
        s1[2] = s1[2] - n
        c.coords(l3, 400, 100, s1[2], 200)
        c.coords(l4, s1[2], 200, 400, 300)
        c.after(0)

    if s2[3] > 200:
        s2[3] = s2[3] - n
        c.coords(l5, 400, 300, 300, s2[3])
        c.coords(l6, 300, s2[3], 200, 300)
        c.after(0)

    if s3[2] < 300:
        s3[2] = s3[2] + n
        c.coords(l7, 200, 300, s3[2], 200)
        c.coords(l8, s3[2], 200, 200, 100)
        c.after(0)

    #global t
    #t = root.after(100, move)
    if not (s[3] < 200 and s1[2] > 300 and s2[3] > 200 and s3[2] < 300):
        #delete_line()
        #start()

        
        while s[3] > 200:
            c.coords(l1, 200, 100, 300, s[3])
            c.coords(l2, 300, s[3], 400, 100)
            s[3] = s[3] + n
            c.after(100)
        
#        if s[3] > 200:
#            s[3] = s[3] - n
#            c.coords(l1, 200, 100, 300, s[3])
#            c.coords(l2, 300, s[3], 400, 100)
#            c.after(0)
#            print(s)
                
#        if s1[2] < 300:
#            s1[2] = s1[2] + n
#            c.coords(l3, 400, 100, s1[2], 200)
#            c.coords(l4, s1[2], 200, 400, 300)
#            c.after(0)
#            print(s1)
                
#        if s2[3] < 200:
#            s2[3] = s2[3] + n
#            c.coords(l5, 400, 300, 300, s2[3])
#            c.coords(l6, 300, s2[3], 200, 300)
#            c.after(0)
                
#        if s3[2] > 300:
#            s3[2] = s3[2] - n
#            c.coords(l7, 200, 300, s3[2], 200)
#            c.coords(l8, s3[2], 200, 200, 100)
#            c.after(0)
               

          

    global t
    t = root.after(100, move)

def stop():
    root.after_cancel(t)


b1 = Button(text='Запуск', command=move)
b1.pack()

b2 = Button(text='Стоп', command=stop)
b2.pack()

start()

# x=300,y=200 координаты центра.
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Не должно быть цикла `while`, цикл должен быть полностью организован через планирование выполнения функции с помощью метода `after`.
2. Разбиваете на две функции (одна для движения внутрь, другая - наружу), работающие абсолютно аналогично друг другу
3. Выпиливаете все вызовы `after` с одним аргументом - они ничего не делают.

```
def move_in():
    global t
    s = c.coords(l1)
    s1 = c.coords(l3)
    print(s1)
    s2 = c.coords(l5)
    s3 = c.coords(l7)

    s[3] = s[3] + n
    c.coords(l1, 200, 100, 300, s[3])
    c.coords(l2, 300, s[3], 400, 100)
    print(s)
    print(s[3])

    s1[2] = s1[2] - n
    c.coords(l3, 400, 100, s1[2], 200)
    c.coords(l4, s1[2], 200, 400, 300)

    s2[3] = s2[3] - n
    c.coords(l5, 400, 300, 300, s2[3])
    c.coords(l6, 300, s2[3], 200, 300)

    s3[2] = s3[2] + n
    c.coords(l7, 200, 300, s3[2], 200)
    c.coords(l8, s3[2], 200, 200, 100)

    # Условие при котором должно продолжаться движение внутрь
    # if s[3] < 200 and s1[2] > 300 and s2[3] > 200 and s3[2] < 300:
    if s[3] < 200:  # Достаточно проверки одного числа, т.к. все линии движутся согласованно
        t = root.after(100, move_in)
    else:  # Иначе начинаем движение наружу
        t = root.after(100, move_out)


def move_out():
    global t
    s = c.coords(l1)
    s1 = c.coords(l3)
    print(s1)
    s2 = c.coords(l5)
    s3 = c.coords(l7)

    s[3] = s[3] - n
    c.coords(l1, 200, 100, 300, s[3])
    c.coords(l2, 300, s[3], 400, 100)
    print(s)
    print(s[3])

    s1[2] = s1[2] + n
    c.coords(l3, 400, 100, s1[2], 200)
    c.coords(l4, s1[2], 200, 400, 300)

    s2[3] = s2[3] + n
    c.coords(l5, 400, 300, 300, s2[3])
    c.coords(l6, 300, s2[3], 200, 300)

    s3[2] = s3[2] - n
    c.coords(l7, 200, 300, s3[2], 200)
    c.coords(l8, s3[2], 200, 200, 100)

    # Условие при котором должно продолжаться движение наружу
    if s[3] > 100:
        t = root.after(100, move_out)
    else:  # Иначе начинаем движение внутрь
        t = root.after(100, move_in)


def stop():
    root.after_cancel(t)


b1 = Button(text='Запуск', command=move_in)
b1.pack()

b2 = Button(text='Стоп', command=stop)
b2.pack()
```

[image: Анимация 1]

---

Еще добавил некоторые улучшения:

- Шаг 10, чтобы линии гарантированно доходили до чисел кратных 10, и не было "недожима" или "перехлеста"
- Сначала вычисляем новые координаты, потом делаем проверку, потом отрисовку, опять же, чтобы не было перехлеста
- Добавил запрет повторного (многократного) запуска движения

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.title('main')
root.geometry('600x800')

c = Canvas(width=600, height=800, bg='white')
c.place(x=0, y=0)

n = 10


def init_lines():
    global l1, l2, l3, l4, l5, l6, l7, l8
    l1 = c.create_line(200, 100, 300, 100)
    l2 = c.create_line(300, 100, 400, 100)
    l3 = c.create_line(400, 100, 400, 200)
    l4 = c.create_line(400, 200, 400, 300)
    l5 = c.create_line(400, 300, 300, 300)
    l6 = c.create_line(300, 300, 200, 300)
    l7 = c.create_line(200, 300, 200, 200)
    l8 = c.create_line(200, 200, 200, 100)


def delete_lines():
    c.delete(l1)
    c.delete(l2)
    c.delete(l3)
    c.delete(l4)
    c.delete(l5)
    c.delete(l6)
    c.delete(l7)
    c.delete(l8)


def move_in():
    global t
    s = c.coords(l1)
    s1 = c.coords(l3)
    s2 = c.coords(l5)
    s3 = c.coords(l7)

    s[3] = s[3] + n
    s1[2] = s1[2] - n
    s2[3] = s2[3] - n
    s3[2] = s3[2] + n

    # Условие при котором должно начинаться движение в противоположном направлении
    if s[3] > 200:
        move_out()
        return

    c.coords(l1, 200, 100, 300, s[3])
    c.coords(l2, 300, s[3], 400, 100)
    c.coords(l3, 400, 100, s1[2], 200)
    c.coords(l4, s1[2], 200, 400, 300)
    c.coords(l5, 400, 300, 300, s2[3])
    c.coords(l6, 300, s2[3], 200, 300)
    c.coords(l7, 200, 300, s3[2], 200)
    c.coords(l8, s3[2], 200, 200, 100)

    t = root.after(100, move_in)


def move_out():
    global t
    s = c.coords(l1)
    s1 = c.coords(l3)
    s2 = c.coords(l5)
    s3 = c.coords(l7)

    s[3] = s[3] - n
    s1[2] = s1[2] + n
    s2[3] = s2[3] + n
    s3[2] = s3[2] - n

    # Условие при котором должно начинаться движение в противоположном направлении
    if s[3] < 100:
        move_in()
        return

    c.coords(l1, 200, 100, 300, s[3])
    c.coords(l2, 300, s[3], 400, 100)
    c.coords(l3, 400, 100, s1[2], 200)
    c.coords(l4, s1[2], 200, 400, 300)
    c.coords(l5, 400, 300, 300, s2[3])
    c.coords(l6, 300, s2[3], 200, 300)
    c.coords(l7, 200, 300, s3[2], 200)
    c.coords(l8, s3[2], 200, 200, 100)

    t = root.after(100, move_out)


t = None


def start():
    if t is None:  # Не запускаем, если уже запущено
        move_in()


def stop():
    global t
    root.after_cancel(t)
    t = None


b1 = Button(text='Запуск', command=start)
b1.pack()

b2 = Button(text='Стоп', command=stop)
b2.pack()

init_lines()

# x=300,y=200 координаты центра.
root.mainloop()
```

[image: Анимация 2]